# boost::optional returning a bool value doesn't always work

Tags: c++, boost

I encountered an issue that I was unable to figure out, hope someone can help 
(gcc 4.7.2, boost 1.59)

```
bool IsValidTest(int val) const
{
   if(val > 0)
       return func(); // func() returns boost::optional<SomeType>;
}
```

I would expect that the optional is implicitly converted to bool , but the compiler complains

```
error: cannot convert boost::optional<SomeType> to bool in return
```

I did see that the ! operator existed so a solution would be to use

```
return !!func();
```

Now, what I cant figure out is why the above won't compile and the following will, why the issue converting to `bool` when returning from the function

```
 if(func())
  // optional actually exists
```

**Note**: I also noticed that `IsValidTest()` did not give any compilation error on visual studio

Any help much appreciated

Comment: boost::optional<SomeType> should be convertible  to two bools I think, so its ambiguous which you want.

Comment: You must be using an older version of M$VS, which didn't support the `explicit` keyword. [M$VS '13 does](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/17/c111417-features-in-vs-2015-preview/)

Comment: yeah i was using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 4):

[`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/optional/optional.hpp) defines an [`explicit` `operator bool`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/core/explicit_operator_bool.hpp).

`explicit` means that the compiler will not do the implicit conversion for you, you have to specify that you want to call the operator.

You used `!!`, but you could have also used `static_cast<bool>()`. It works for `if` because the `if` statement has special rules regarding `operator bool`, namely that it ignores the `explicit` identifier when evaluating its expression.

Comment: Re “It works for `if` because the `if` statement expects a `bool`”, no, it works for `if` because an `if` expects a *condition*, which has a special rule for `explicit operator bool()`. For example, just using the `optional` directly as initializer for a `bool` variable will not work.

Comment: I did not really understand your point Re "just using the optional directly as initializer for a bool variable will not work" could you please give an example

Comment: @BubbleBoy My explanation was a bit off. It said that this `bool b = returnOptional();` would work, but it does not

Comment: @BubbleBoy: `bool b = some_optional;` won't compile. This context requires a `bool` value but there is no implicit conversion to `bool`. A context requiring a `bool` value is not enough to trigger the `explicit` conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> **”** a solution would be to use
>
> ```
> return !!func();
> ```

**No.** Explicitly converting the `optional` to `bool` just checks for the presence of a value, i.e. whether it's empty or not. This is via an `explicit operator bool()`, much the same as with an iostream.

An `optional` instance acts conceptually as a pointer that can be null, and the explicit conversion to `bool` checks for nullness.

To get at the object pointed to, if any, use `*` to logically dereference the (conceptual) pointer. This throws an exception if the `optional` is empty. Or in the pointer view, if the (conceptual) pointer is null.

Since you want a single `bool` value as return value from your function, you will have to decide on what you want in the case where the `optional` is empty.